# Close TopLevel window after command

Tags: python

I'm doing a simple compressor in Python for a school assignment, my problem here is that when you enter the name of the file, a little window has to appear with a button that will execute the tar command, I want that window to close after it does the command but I dont know why, here's my code

```
def crea_arxiu():
    global aux
    if v.get() is 1 or v.get() is 2 or v.get() is 3 or v.get() is 4:
        f = open('fitxers.txt','w')
        for i in range(llista2.size()):
            f.write(llista2.get(i)+'\n')
        f.close()
        print 'Arxius a comprimir:',llista2.size()  
        obre_finestra()

        if aux is 1:
            print 'AUX IS TRUE'
            subprocess.call(['rm','fitxers.txt'])
    else: 
        print 'Escolleix una opcio'
#Aquest mètode crea i mostra la pantalla per guardar el nom
#i i la finestra amb la comanda que executara
def obre_finestra():
    global aux
    ruta_text = StringVar()

    finestra2=Toplevel(finestra)
    finestra2.minsize(0,0)
    finestra2.title('Comanda a executar:')
    ruta = Label(finestra2, width=60, relief=SUNKEN, textvariable=ruta_text)
    ruta.pack(side=LEFT)
    boto = Button(finestra2, text = 'Executar', command = lambda: executar_commanda(nom_arxiu, tipus_comp))
    boto.pack(side = RIGHT)
    nom_arxiu = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Guardar com')

    if v.get() is 1:
        tipus_comp = 'cf'
        nom_arxiu = nom_arxiu+'.tar'
    elif v.get() is 2:
        tipus_comp = 'czf'
        nom_arxiu = nom_arxiu+'.tgz'
    elif v.get() is 3:
        tipus_comp = 'cjf'
        nom_arxiu = nom_arxiu+'.tbz'
    elif v.get() is 4:
        tipus_comp = 'cJf'
        nom_arxiu = nom_arxiu+'.txz'
    ruta_text.set('tar '+tipus_comp+' '+nom_arxiu+' '+'fitxers de la llista')
    if aux is 1:
        finestra2.destroy()

def executar_commanda(nom,tipus_comp):
    global aux 
    aux = 1
    subprocess.call(['tar',tipus_comp,nom,'-T','fitxers.txt'])
```

The order of the functions is: crea_arxiu -> obre_finestra (summons the asksaveasfilename and the little window) , and when i press 'Execute' does executar_commanda and then i want the window to be killed

Before entering the name of the file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUxzN.jpg

After the name is given:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIkGX.jpg

So at the end I just want the path window to be closed after it does de 'Executar' button, so much thank you guys and sry for my english not being so good ^^'